# Synchronous start of the event

Tags: ios, swift, time, synchronization

Is there a way to run the code simultaneously on different devices? Let's say I want that when I click on a button on one of the devices, the function starts simultaneously on both the first and the second device? I tried to use a timer with a time check for 3 seconds ahead, but the function is triggered with a delay of 0.5 seconds on the second device

```
func getEventTime() -> UInt64{
    let now = Date()
    let interval = now.timeIntervalSince1970
    let result = (UInt64(interval) + (3)) * 1000
    return result
}

func getCurrentTime() -> UInt64{
    let now = Date()
    let interval = now.timeIntervalSince1970
    let result = UInt64(interval * 1000)
    return result
}

    func startTimer(time : UInt64){
       Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.0001, repeats: true) { timer in
        
        switch getCurrentTime() {
        
        case time - 1000 :
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                countdownImageTimer.image = UIImage(named: "Start")
            }
            break
        
        case time :
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                countdownImageTimer.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            self.setShips()
            timer.invalidate()
            break
        default:
            break
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: just use fireAt timer and set the same date. Btw  0.0001 willl try to run your method 10.000 times per second. Do you really think this will solve your issue?

Comment: Can you provide a valid code example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52927733/2303865

Comment: If the time on the devices is not exactly synchronized, there is a difference of 0.5 mls, so this method will not work?

Comment: This is very unlikely if they are setting their date automatically. There is no way to make sure they are in perfect sync unless you are sending a signal to both of them over the network and it will always depend on each device connection to determine who will get the data first.